# How to log error messages in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

How to log the error messages in a recipe.

For EX: My recipe here is

```
#
# Cookbook:: mkdir
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2018, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

bash 'extract_module' do
code <<-EOH
mkdir -p /tmp/#{node['main']['directory']}
EOH
Chef::Log.info "Directory Created"
#puts "Directory created"

end
```

Where is the log file actually created ??? --> Chef::Log.info "Directory Created"

How can i control my recipe to stop if

```
mkdir -p /tmp/#{node['main']['directory']}
```

actually fails??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it depends on your operating system.

For a windows machine your logs will most likely be at the directory `C:\chef\log`.

For a linux machine, it should default to `/etc/chef/log`

You should find log files with names like `client-run_20181024124200.log`.
This log file will contain your `Chef::Log.info "Directory Created"`

I would like to point out that, you can actually specify where you want your logs to be written to. To do this, first navigate to and open the file `C:\chef\client.rb` on a windows machine or `/etc/chef/client.rb` on a linux box.

You can now change the line `log_location       STDOUT` to your own directory like
 `log_location       C:\logs\cheflogs`

Answer (score 0):

The resource will fail the converge of bash has a non-zero exit code so the easy way is to add `set -e` to your script. Or use a directory resource instead.

Comment: I'm not concerned on the code, All i want to know is where is the logs created when i include the below line in the recipe

***********
Chef::Log.info "Directory Created"
***********

Comment: Remember that log is printed at compile time, not converge time. Read https://coderanger.net/two-pass/

Answer (score 0):

This was the question that a search found when trying to figure out where Chef Workstation stores the log file (the error when failing to converge was the unhelpful `Please examine the log file for a detailed cause of failure` but without any indication of where that file should be.

Google was certain that the answer was `/var/log/opscode`, but it is not.

Ultimately, I found the answer at https://docs.chef.io/workstation/config/#location .  This shows how to configure that, and more importantly, that the default is `"$USERHOME/.chef-workstation/logs/default.log"`